# Execute shell command from PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, xampp, libxml2

I want to run some command from php code. When I run code from terminal it works fine without error. But when I run same command from php code it gives me error like this:

```
/usr/bin/php: /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /usr/bin/php)
```

I run command : `locate libxml2.so`, this command gives output like this:

```
/opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so
/opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2
/opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2.8.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.0
```

So, seems like 2.9.0 version is already installed. So, how to execute command without this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeed. Install phpcs (or any module you want to execute by apache of xampp) then install inside "bin" of xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Use [shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec) function to exec it.
Try `<?php echo shell_exec('locate libxml2.so');`

Comment: That also gives me same output as I pasted in question.

Comment: Ah, I'm not understand before that you mean. You should fix your php.ini configuraion, or use
`cp /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2 /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2.old && rm /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2 && ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2`

Comment: disable means?? can you explain me in more detail?

Comment: @SavanKoradia I updated my previous comment, could you read it?

Comment: Hi tried but now it gives me error:
/usr/bin/php: relocation error: /usr/bin/php: symbol X509_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

Comment: Try use `locate libcrypto.so` to find normal file and create symlink to that file as in previous my comment.

Comment: @SavanKoradia what OS you using? Best of all should be install apache + php + mysql from scratch.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @SavanKoradia to install LAMP from scratch you should remove your current lamp and make all instructions from this link http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-13.04-lamp

Comment: I needed php 5.4.25 for client project. So, I installed xampp in ubuntu.